# Running a rgeom sample and storing the mean and SD of each replication

Tags: r, random, sample

Trying to run the follow rgeom 500 times and store the mean and sd for each replication.

```
rgeom(100, prob = .2)
```

so far I have:

```
geom_means = rep(NA, 500)
geom_sd = rep(NA, 500)
X_geom500 <- replicate(500, {
  samp <- rgeom(100, prob = .2)
  geom_means = round(mean(samp),2)
})


X_geom500_sd <- replicate(500, {
  samp <- rgeom(100, prob = .2)
  round(sd(samp),2)
})
```

I can get a vector of 500 means and 500 sd's if I run the code separately but I don't think they are matching. I tried creating a for loop to store the means and SD for each iteration but I don't think it worked right.

```
for i in range(1:500):
  sample[i] <- rgeom(100, prob = .2)
  geom_means[i] <-  mean(sample[i])
  geom_sd[i] <- sd(sample[i])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get both mean and sd from each replication:

```
set.seed(123)

n_rep <- 5

samp_geom <- function(n, prob) {
  samp <- rgeom(n, prob)
  return(list(mean = round(mean(samp), 2), sd = round(sd(samp, 2))))
}

replicate(n_rep, samp_geom(100, .2))

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
mean 3.78 3.64 4.09 3.68 3.73
sd   4    4    5    5    4
```

Store the resulting values in separate vectors like this:

```
geom_means <- unlist(samps["mean", ])
geom_means
# [1] 3.78 3.64 4.09 3.68 3.73

geom_sd <- unlist(samps["sd", ])
geom_sd
# [1] 4 4 5 5 4
```

Comment: thanks @andrew_reece. Problem is I need stored vectors of each mean and sd not just a list of them. I eventually need to create a histogram of the means and compute the expected value of the samples.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "stored vectors", can you update your post with some example expected output (at least the format)?

Comment: sorry. I mean there should be a value of geom_means = the mean of each geom replication. Then a value of geom_sd = the sd of each geom replication. That way I can put each list of values in a table or matrix.

Comment: Ok - I updated but not sure if that's what you mean?  It's just taking the vectors out of the `replicate()` output and storing them in separate variables...not sure if I'm missing something.